# Extract image from web page

Tags: html, web, canvas, html5-canvas

How to extract the image from this https://www.google.com/maps/@45.8118462,15.9725486,3a,75y/data=!3m7!1e2!3m5!1sAF1QipOH6lgU7bug2ndyW-9-Uq0kgKqcKDtnGei2N5Qo!2e10!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipOH6lgU7bug2ndyW-9-Uq0kgKqcKDtnGei2N5Qo%3Dw150-h150-k-no-p!7i3024!8i4032

(If the link disappears let me describe how to reproduce the question. *Find any shop on Google Maps that has the "shop title image" appearing in the shop details on the left side when you click on that shop. Click on that image to expand it across the whole viewport.*)

I found the `<canvas>` element that I guess contains the image. I tried to do `.getContext('2d')` on that canvas element, but I keep getting null.

Comment: I am not sure about extracting it, but I can see the image in the network tab. https://lh3.ggpht.com/p/AF1QipOH6lgU7bug2ndyW-9-Uq0kgKqcKDtnGei2N5Qo=s512

Comment: Oh. Interesting. That would basically satisfy my needs. But for the sake of HTML and JS knowledge improvement, I'd like to also know how to extract it from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting `null` when doing `getContext("2d")` it's because an other type of context was created already, in this case, a `"webgl"` one.

To convert that canvas to a new image, you'd normally call `canvas.toBlob()` (whatever the context type).
And if you need to crop that canvas content, you'd draw it on an other canvas.
But since they did not prevent the WebGL context to throw away its drawing buffer (by passing `preserveDrawingBuffer` in the `getContext` call), you'll only get a transparent image back from it.

Anyway none of these methods will retrieve the original image, but they will create a new image entirely (probably of lesser quality, and bigger in size). To retrieve the original image, check the network tab of your dev tools, or if you need to do it programmatically, inject a script that will spoof all `fetch`, XHR and `HTMLImageElement` objects in order to log their resource URL. But that becomes dirty.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly there is no way to get the image **from this canvas** (as it is seen on the canvas)?

Comment: @croraf yes, well you could actually grab it if you somehow managed to append you script's call exactly in the same rendering frame as their call to paint that image. I managed to do so by doing something like `onclick = () => requestAnimationFrame(()=>canvas.toBlob( callback ))` before clicking to the link that opens that image, but I assume it was fluke. Or you could also insert a script through a user-script with `@run-at document-start` which would overwrite `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext` to always pass the `preserveDrawingBuffer` option for webgl contexts.